# Meaning of "I had a dream it would end this way"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, modal-verbs

I’m watching a show, Community, and I have a question about a line of it.

Please watch it: [Community](https://youtu.be/rXwr890Pf_A).

The guy says “I had a dream it would end this way”. What does it mean?

Does “a dream” mean a dream in the night? or a hope?

And why did he use “would” here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dream), **dream** as two meanings:

> **SLEEP**: a series of events or images that happen in your mind when you are sleeping
>
> **HOPE**: something that you want to happen very much but that is not very likely

What happens next in the clip is certainly not something that Troy, the speaker, would "want to happen very much", so the **HOPE** option is not likely. If the script writers stuck to the dictionary definition, the **SLEEP** option is the only possibility. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dream) does not offer any other useful possibilities.

As Peter suggested, it may be a misquote of a standard expression, and the script writers are using the word **dream** incorrectly.

---

The word **would** is used because, at some time in the past, Troy dreamed

> It **will** end this way

When he later reported what he dreamt, he [backshifted](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm) the tense, so **will** became **[would](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would)**.

> I had a dream [that] it **would** end this way

Comment: Thanks. Then what does dream mean here? Does it mean a feeling as Peter said?

Comment: Oh, and can’t “would” mean “an imagined situation” here?

Comment: @MangoGummy If you describe something that you imagine now but you can reasonably expect it to happen, you say  "I **will** be a famous singer one day", If you describe now something that you imagine **hypothetically** happening in the future, then you use **would** because it's a hypothetical situation. "I **would** hate to miss the show" In Troy's sentence, he is talking about something he dreamed **in the past** that is really is happening now. The past form **would** is used because he dreamed it in the past, not because it's hypothetical.

Comment: @MangoGummy As I have demonstrated, you can look up the meanings of the word in the dictionary,  and only one meaning of **dream** is valid in this context- something you do when you sleep. I cannot tell you whether the script writers intended that meaning, or whether they were abusing the word in an incorrectly quoted expression. You would have to ask the script writers about that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I ask about “I would hate to miss the show”? Then does it mean the speaker doesn’t miss the show but it might happen in the future?

Comment: @MangoGummy  No, in this context **miss** means **fail to attend**. it means that the show is an event planned in the future, and the speaker intends to go to the show, and will try very hard not to miss it (fail to attend).

Comment: Thanks. Returning to “a dream”, what makes some people consider it as “a feeling”? If I wanna use it as a dream from sleeping, what should I say then?

Comment: @MangoGummy: A dream for sleeping is the correct meaning. The usage in your question is unusual. People might think that the script writers intended to use the word "feeling" because that's the word used in the normal expression "I had a feeling it would end this way."..

Comment: @Man Java did not "demonstrate" that the meaning of *dream* in this context must mean dream-in-sleep. In fact, it more likely means *hope:* The event can easily be seen as a hero dying in glory, which is something many hope for, perhaps more in the imagination, as a fantasy (a kind of hope) if not in reality. Next, *I'd hate to miss the show* does not necessarily mean "the speaker intends to go to the show, and will try very hard not to miss it". It could also represent a hypothetical: (If I had spent $1,000 on a ticket like you did) I'd hate to miss the show. (If, like you, I had ...

Comment: a chance to see Elton John, (if the Beatles came back to life and were going to perform, etc.) ... *I'd hate to miss the show.* If it's a show that I'm expected to see but don't want to see, I might use the sentence in an ironic sense, meaning *I'd love to miss the show.* (Again, *would* used for modal remoteness/hypothetical/not-real.) To the potential charge that my examples are "unusual", well, writers of works of art like TV shows *often* use language unusually. If they didn't, they probably wouldn't have work.

Answer (score 0):

The usual saying is

> I had a **feeling** it would end this way.

It is a premonition that *something* will happen in the future.
To use "***dream***" is just a variation.
It means he had a *strong feeling* that whatever happened was going to happen.

Comment: Thanks. Then would is the past tense of will here?

Answer (score 0):

It's meaning is quite plain:

He tells us that he once had a dream that it (his life) would end in the way that was about to happen (being shot by a band of Stormtroopers).

*Dream* is likely used to mean *fantasy,* whether he is meant to say it was literally a dream that occurred during sleep, a hope, or a hope expressed through a dream during sleep. (Or a dream during sleep that was expressed as a hope!)

Why did the writer of the show have the character say this? That is for us to understand or speculate about.

What I get is the idea that in the past he imagined himself dying in glory, fighting for good against evil.

Would is a modal used to mark tense: the *future of the past,* as it's called here:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#/12

(See Usage of Specific Verbs > Will and Would.)

To say, as in another answer, that it is an example of backshifting, seems to me a stretch, at best, or incorrect.

He is not reporting speech indirectly. That would require something like *I once said that I had a dream ... ".*

Consider: *The house looked ugly then, but it ***would*** get a new coat of paint a few years later.*

That is a declaration, not involving what anyone once said, (or thought, if we want to conceptualize *knew* in the instant sentence an act of "inner speech" that is being reported).

The reason for using *would* is the same. It was something that occurred in the past that was about the future at that time.